# Page View Controller: UILabel and UIImageview empty on first page

Tags: uilabel, xcode5, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a UIPageViewController to display items from a JSON file. It works fine except for the first page which displays nothing on loading, but if I come back, it works.

Code is as follows:

```
#import "SJPagesViewController.h"
#import "SJChildViewController.h"

@interface SJPagesViewController ()

@end

@implementation SJPagesViewController
@synthesize urlToFollow, data,articlesArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   ...
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    CGFloat window_height = ([self window_height]-30.0);
    CGFloat window_width  = [self window_width];
    CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,window_width , window_height);

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:pageFrame];

    SJChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


    //Download JSON
    NSError *error=nil;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToFollow];

    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

    NSArray *response = [dictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

    articlesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response];
    //NSLog(@"articlesArray = %@", articlesArray);


}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(SJChildViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(SJChildViewController *)viewController index];
    index++;

    if (index == articlesArray.count) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (CGFloat) window_height   {
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height;
}

- (CGFloat) window_width   {
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (SJChildViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    SJChildViewController *childViewController = [[SJChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SJChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    childViewController.index = index;
    childViewController.arrayCount = self.articlesArray.count;
    childViewController.model = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"modelo"];
    childViewController.price = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"precio"];
    childViewController.make = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"marca"];
    childViewController.imageUrl = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"photoUrl"];

    return childViewController;

}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
    if (articlesArray.count >5) {
        return 5;
    }else return [articlesArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
    return 0;
}

@end
```

And ChildViewController to display items:

```
@implementation SJChildViewController
@synthesize activityIndicator,imageUrl,price,model,make;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    ....
}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Activity indicator
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.scrrenNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Artículo %ld de %ld", ((long)self.index+1), (long)self.arrayCount];

    self.lblMake.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.lblMake.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",make];

    //Donload image
    //Download image from url
    NSURL *url_1= [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request_1 = [NSURLRequest   requestWithURL:url_1];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request_1
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                               UIImage  *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                               [self.articleImage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:YES];
                           }];
    //Activity indicator

    self.lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",price];
    self.lblModel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.lblModel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",model];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

How can I make it work from the first moment?

Comment: I am having the same problem, how did you download the JSON file & populate the Array first? I've tried several methods, but the viewcontroller is loaded first.

Comment: did you ever figure this out, can you please help me out here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713692/api-json-uipageviewcontroller-optional-nil/29713832#29713832

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luis, I don't have access to xcode right now but it appears your issue is that you are instantiating `childViewController` while `articlesArray` is empty.

In `viewDidLoad` you are downloading your json file and populating `articlesArray` after you call your helper method `viewControllerAtIndex`.

Try downloading your json file and populating the array first like you have here.

```
//Download JSON
NSError *error=nil;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToFollow];

data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *response = [dictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

articlesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response];
```

Then create your pageViewController and populate it like you did here.

```
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

CGFloat window_height = ([self window_height]-30.0);
CGFloat window_width  = [self window_width];
CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,window_width , window_height);

self.pageController.dataSource = self;
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:pageFrame];

SJChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Oh! It was so easy now... I made a lot of changes in the childviewcontroller but didn't think of changing the download section at Pages...